# Can I drop 'That' in the following sentence?

Tags: optional-that

Should I include "That" before "comes" in the following sentence? My colleague says in some places "That" can be dropped.

**Which one is correct?**

> What’s better than a price hike **that** comes with an irresistible offer?
>
> What’s better than a price hike comes with an irresistible offer?

Comment: The second one isn't right unless you remove the verb too. "What’s better than a price hike with an irresistible offer?" But it is true that in some places "that" can be dropped.

Comment: Your colleague's qualification of *in **some** places* is correct. But in this particular sentence, as indicated in the previous comment, *that* cannot be dropped without making additional changes to the sentence. For a discussion of this in general (where it *can* be dropped), see the question [He discovered that his father had a special box in the basement](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/455779/291924) and my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st sentence is correct and the second one is incorrect.

> What’s better than a price hike **that comes** with an irresistible offer? ✔

(Here, **'that'** cannot be omitted because the that-clause modifies its antecedent ("a price hike") in the main clause.)

> What’s better than a price hike with an irresistible offer? ✔

(Here, "that + verb" has been omitted, and the PP "with an Irresistible offer" modifies the NP 'a price hike'.)

You can omit 'that' in reported speech :

Peter says, "Price hike is a problem during the lockdown."

= Peter says (**that**) price hike is a problem during the lockdown.

Besides, when the that-clause refers to the opinion of the subject, you can omit 'that' :

I think (**that**) price hike is a problem during the lockdown.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Cleo, I teach English for Brazilian people.
I've noticed something pretty simple that doesn't require deep knowledge on linguistics or related areas.
When it comes to **verbs following "that"**, we cannot omit "that", no matter the verbal conjugation.
I hope this helps.